# APNS not received after server migration

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Our iOS app successfully implemented APNS. Sometimes its not getting received but almost 90% of time its ok.

Now we are required to migrate the whole server-side (which is written in PHP) codes.
After few hours, everything was done and thought migration was completed (all webview was correctly shown, user's data etc.). However, when my colleague try to send push notification to my iOS app, it failed to receive. The server log stating that the APNS was successfully sent and no errors. Interestingly, when he try to send APNS through web browser (hit the URL to send the command), it's successfully received.

Now we don't know where to go from here and don't know what to do. Are we missing some process required in the case like this? For example, should we re-create Certification files for APNS if we want to migrate the whole system? Is there any iOS code at all to modify when the server was migrated? (Other than referral to the server URL. We have already checked that)

I know that the question is too vague but it's just happened and we really can't think of any reason. If there's any guidance for server migration for APNS, it would totally appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You're right, way too many unknowns to give you a straight-forward answer :)

But, if I understand correctly, when you trigger the PHP from a web browser, the push works. When it's triggered via command line, it doesn't.

Make sure that the user who is executing your script via command line belongs to a group that has enough rights to execute all the statements in your PHP script. For example, if you're using the fwrite command, the user executing the script must belong to a group that has access to the file system.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the tip Nick! We always make sure to do so. We still don't know why this is happining, but perhaps my colleague will sort it out. But probably the problem will come out again anyway (they always like this...).